# Filter DataFrame by mixed data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table and I want to remove all rows which do have a "C" in their `col1` value.

```
     col1  col2
0       1     3
1       2     4
2    C345     3
3  A56665     4
4   34553     3
5  353535     4
```

The code below seems to consider only rows which `col1` value is a str. Why is it the case?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2, "C345", "A56665", 34553, 353535], 'col2': [3, 4,3, 4,3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.col1.astype(str)
print(df.dtypes)

print(df.loc[df.col1.str.contains("C") == False])
```

result

```
     col1  col2
3  A56665     4
```

Desired result:

```
     col1  col2
0       1     3
1       2     4
3  A56665     4
4   34553     3
5  353535     4
```

I use Python 3.6 and pandas 0.23.4, numpy 1.15.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If check output of str.contains get missing values for numeric values:

```
print(df.col1.str.contains("C"))
0      NaN
1      NaN
2     True
3    False
4      NaN
5      NaN
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Solution is use parameter `na` to [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and invert boolean mask by `~`:

```
print(df[~df.col1.str.contains("C", na=False)])
     col1  col2
0       1     3
1       2     4
3  A56665     4
4   34553     3
5  353535     4
```

**Details**:

```
print(df.col1.str.contains("C", na=False))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool

print(~df.col1.str.contains("C", na=False))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert first to string, then proceed as usual:

```
df.loc[df.col1.astype(str).str.contains(r"C") == False]
```